# What is the best way to convert VB if statement that return a string to C#

Tags: c#, vb.net

I have a VB "if statement" like

```
tagAttribute="<%=If(Model.booleanProperty, "true", "false" )%>"
```

Would I have to do something like

```
if(Model.booleanProperty)
  {string booleanProperty = "true"};
else
  { string booleanProperty = "false"};

tagAttribute = booleanProperty;
```

or is there a nicer way to do it in C#? 
I am also using Razor if that makes a difference.

Comment: You don't like `Model.booleanProperty.ToString()` ?

Comment: For reference, here's the ternary operator that other people have mentioned: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty67wk28(v=vs.80).aspx

Comment: Sorry I didn't mention there's other places in the code that require return of different string value such as If(Model.IsOpen, "", " display_none")

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use inline syntax for C#

```
var myString = Model.booleanProperty ? "true" : "false";
```

to write this for Razor, remember to put "@" before the C# expression, so the Razor engine can evaluate it

```
tagAttribute='@(Model.booleanProperty ? "true" : "false" )'
```

Comment: Yea I actually tried this also but it failed because I used @{}. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

You can do that like this:

```
<%= Model.booleanProperty ? "true" : "false" %>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simply write:

```
<%= Model.booleanProperty.ToString().ToLower() %>
```

Answer (score 0):

`Model.booleanProperty ? "true" : "false"`

Also, you might find this useful for things like this in future - I wouldn't trust it with converting LINQ though.

http://www.developerfusion.com/tools/convert/csharp-to-vb/

Answer (score 0):

Either use

```
tagAttribute = Model.booleanProperty.ToString()
```

or

```
tagAttribute = Model.booleanProperty ? "true" : "false";
```